# ZF2 - How to set selected multiple options in Select Input

Tags: php, select, zend-framework2

I have Select with multiple attribute. I can check multi values but I couldn't figure out how to set selected values by default. I tried:

```
/* @var $tagsSelect \Zend\Form\Element\Select */
$tagsSelect = $form->get('tag_entity_connection')->get('tags'); // it's my Select with multiple attribute
$tagsSelect->setValue(array(4,8));
```

but it doesn't work. Works only when I passing one value, ex. `setValue(4)` - doesn't work with array of values.

HTML of my Select looks like:

```
 <select name="tag_entity_connection[tags][]" class="input block select2" multiple="multiple" id="tag_entity_connection[tags][]">
    <option value="4" selected="">Tag czy</option>
    <option value="8">Tag dwa</option>
 </select>
```

**OK. Finally I figured out that problem was with my ViewHelper.**

Comment: Please provide some extra information about version of zf2 You're using, and how You render select element in Your view. Are you using Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormSelect ?

Comment: ZF2 version 2.3. I'm using my own ViewHelper to render form. I added HTML output of Select in my post.

Comment: When You're using your own helper to render Select, you should handle rendering on your own so look to https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Form/View/Helper/FormSelect.php for examle how it is done in original Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormSelect